# How to get error if phone balance is insufficiant in smsManager

Tags: java, android, smsmanager

I'm using cardviews in android and sending sms while clicking on one of them with smsManager. How can i display an error for the user if no balance in his phone?

Comment: There is no API in Android for determining the balance on their account, in part because not all phone plans have that sort of thing. You would need to contact each of the mobile carriers and ask them if they have some sort of Web service API that you could use.

Comment: oh, thanks for answering.